# Effective algorithm for finding 16x16 pixel same squares in a big image - C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing

i am coding a software at visual studio 2010 by using C#. what does this software do is finding same squares at the image after a square selected. every square is composed by 16x16 pixel. my current algorithm starts from first pixel and scan the entire image pixel by pixel comparing to determine same pixel squares with the selected one. this takes really big time. Can you suggest me any better way ?

also every square is ordered. so they start like 0 - 16 - 32 - 48

a square can not start from 5 or 65 etc

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could cache a checksum of each image-region. Then you would only have to check ones that match the checksum for equality.

Let's assume each image is 16x16 rgb elements. You could do this (and yes, it will have integer overflow.)

All of this is in pseudo code - you're expected to be able to translate this to C#.

Add an int to the field image class, or create an image wrapper with an int as the 'checksum'

```
int checksum = 0
for each pixel in image {
   checksum += pixel.red + pixel.blue + pixel.green
   // you could do anything you wanted here, like
   // checksum *= 17 + pixel.red
   // checksum *= 17 + pixel.blue
   // checksum *= 17 + pixel.green
   // just make it "unique enough", like a hashcode
}
image.checksum = checksum
```

Now when you go to search you can go like this:

```
/**
 * equals method before: 
 */
boolean equals(image a, image b) {
  for x = 0..15 do /* all 16 pixels in X */
    for y = 0..15 do /* all 16 pixels in Y */
      if a.getPixel(x,y) != b.getPixel(x,y) return false;
  return true;
}

/**
 * equals method after: 
 *.
boolean equals(image a, image b) {
  /* this check lets you skip the loop in most cases */
  /* still have to verify that the image is equal pixel for pixel though */
  if a.checksum != b.checksum return false;
  for x = 0..15 do /* all 16 pixels in X */
    for y = 0..15 do /* all 16 pixels in Y */
      if a.getPixel(x,y) != b.getPixel(x,y) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: i dont see anything here which will make some speed improvement when compared to mine

Comment: the checksum - if the checksum doesn't match (it's cached, so you only ever calculate it once) you can skip the entire process of checking an image.

Comment: @PokemonCraft: The point is that he's computing and storing a checksum for each 16x16 region. So when you want to see if one region is the same as another, you go through the list of checksums, looking for those that match the checksum of the region you're comparing against. This is a simple integer comparison and in most cases the checksums won't match.  When there is a match, you have to do a detailed comparison of the two regions. This method is much faster because you don't have to do the detailed comparison very often.

Comment: @Jim thanks. It really shines when the images contain mostly the same pixels (say, they all have the same background color for transparent filtering). Thanks more for the detailed explanation of how the checksum works.

Comment: there is a 100% secure way. sum all the rgb codes as string. then md5 hash them. this will be square (16x16) pixels checksum. this will take time only at first time run (init). than it will be very fast.

Comment: That would greatly reduce the risk of a collision. It would not guarantee 100% that you wouldn't get one. A 16x16 rgb picture has 2^6144 different combination. There are only 2^128 different MD5 hashes. This means there's a 1/(2^128) chance of a collision. Yes, it's small. But it's there never the less, which means you would still have to check the image. So, if you still have to check sometimes, why go through the bother of string creation and md5 hash when you can have an int (which is 1/(2^32) chance) and have your checksum a lot faster to calculate?

Comment: well i made some improvements at the code so it is not necessary anymore for my current size images :) sandy bridge 2600k @ 4.8 GHZ handles really fast ^^ but at least now i know a faster way to handle bigger size images.

Comment: @glowcoder: Actually, the chance of a collision when using the MD5 hashing scheme is somewhat greater than 1/(2^128). This is another instance of the birthday paradox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem. You're right in that using MD5 wouldn't give any appreciable performance gain. In fact, it would probably be slower than using a simple 32-bit hash or checksum.

Comment: @Jim I see your point. We're both right. In every case, there's a 1/(2^128) chance of a collision. So if the entire sprite map consisted of 1 image, the overall chance would be 1/(2^128). Of course, that wouldn't be much of a sprite map, so obviously the chance will increase the more we add. An important element of the birthday problem is that everyone has (about) a 1/365 chance to have a birthday as someone else, even if the odds of a birthday collision increase as more people enter the room.

Answer (score 1):

One algorithm I know of to compare how similar two images are is the root mean square algorithm.  I've used this in several programs and it's always been pretty fast.  This simply sums up the differences, does some math, and the difference will be 'how close' the two images are to each other.

But, if the access is slow for comparison of each pixel, then access will still be slow (albeit slightly faster) adding them all up (or checksumming it).

Another option would be to add a short-circuit.  The second any pixel at all doesn't match, you can claim the whole picture doesn't match.

I would be curious why this is going slow, though.  The image would have to be incredibly large for it to not count.  Are you using Bitmap.GetPixel()?

Comment: i am not trying to find whether 2 image is similiar or not. i just need to code the image square by square at my software so this will speed up selecting squares and assigning them a value. here how i get pixels        Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);  and my computer has 8 cores and working @4.8 ghz but software doesnt work multithreaded atm :D